# Easier way to fully decode this string?

Tags: php, decode, urldecode

Instead of doing this

```
urldecode(urldecode(urldecode(curl_exec($ch))));
```

The output from curl_exec is encoded more than once, is there a way I can decode it fully with only one call to a function?

I just wrote this function and it works perfectly

```
function decodeSource($encodedSource){
    while($encodedSource != urldecode($encodedSource)){
        $encodedSource = urldecode($encodedSource);
    }
return $encodedSource;
}
```

Comment: "The output from curl_exec is encoded more than once" --- by whom?

Comment: And ... how would such a decode function know how many times to iterate its urldecode()?

Comment: I am loading a webpage using the cURL extension, curl_exec() returns the source of the webpage, and the webpage is encoded, and has \u0026, \u0026amp; as well that I would like to have decoded

Comment: That probably means that the page being fetched has `urlencode`d the content... So just remove whatever is encoding the content multiple times and it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: ghoti, thats what I was curious about as well

Comment: \u0026 is unicode, looks like whatever is being returned is going through something other than `urlencode`. btw, calling `urlencode` multiple times on a url has no effect, it can't encode it more.

Answer (score 1):

What about using your own function?

```
function multiurldecode($url, $count=1) {
  for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++)
    $url=urldecode($url);
  return($url);
}
```

This is off the top of my head, untested....

**UPDATE** per comment:

Not a bad idea at all!  Here it is in code.

```
function multiurldecode($url, $count=1) {
  if ($count==0) {
    for( $last=urldecode($url); $last!=$url; $url=urldecode($url) )
      $last=$url;
  } else {
    for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++)
      $url=urldecode($url);
  }
  return($url);
}
```

Again, I haven't tested this, but it runs fine in my head.  :)  The idea here is that if you provide a count of zero, the for loop will keep running until the decoded URL is the same as its source.

Comment: You could add a check to see if the string is different than the decoded string... And then stop when they are the same.

Comment: Yes, but that might go too far.  What if the string you *want* is the second last urlencode?  I think we need more information from the OP.

Comment: edited the original post with a function that I wrote, works just how I needed it too, ty all